# Can't boot into windows or CD

Tags: windows-7, debian, multi-boot, grub

This is my third reinstall of Debian, this time because I wanted to update from wheezy to Jessie, but it wouldn't run anymore so I switched back to windows and deleted the Debian partition and restarted. It booted into grub rescue mode, so I turned it off, because I didn't have the CD with me. When I got the CD and turned it on, I am unable to boot from the CD, no matter how much I press f12. I have the Toshiba Satellite P755D. I have both the windows repair disk and Debian install CD, just can't boot into it.

Comment: For those wondering, i think my warranty is up, and i have access to a screwdriver. Just be sure to give clear instruction on that if it is necessary.

Comment: Also i been able to boot into a CD before, considering this is my third time.

Comment: Another thing is that it used to show press f12 for settings, but it doesn't do that anymore.

Comment: when it boots, what does it say when it stops booting up? WHere is it stuck? Anyways have you checked BIOS settings? Is CD set to first boot option or not? F2 I think... press F2 and then restart computer and hold until BIOS pulls up. CHeck the order of the boot.

Comment: Just tried f1-f12 and none of them did anything different. I keep on booting into grub rescue. The error is ”error: no such partition. " which is because i deleted grub.

Comment: quick boot... hold f2 and keep holding it when you restart it.

Comment: Nope that isn't working. It keeps on going into grub.

Comment: Try taking out the HDD -> boot the laptop so you can get to the BIOS -> set the first boot device to be the CD/DVD drive -> reconnect the HDD -> insert Windows DVD -> start computer and wait for "Press any key to boot to CD..."